# How to add the tracking code in angular js

Tags: angularjs, tracking

I need to track how many times each page is viwed by user.....Here What the problem is when the page moved to another page its not redirecting so its not trackinf the count

here is my code

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-134846467-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-134846467-1');
</script>
```

Comment: What do you use for router? Do you use an angular router (is it a Single Page App) or are your pages rendered server-side? If it's the first one you could listen to en event on your router code on every state change